# JS: Facebook Login SDK not returning email

Tags: javascript

I didn't find the answer in the other questions listed as this.  I tried the solution (I'll show below) but it didn't work.
I'm being told by the backend developers that when they authenticate the token I am sending to them, it only contains the name and ID fields. 
I tried adding a called to `FB.login` and specifying:

```
var url = '/me?fields=name,email';
FB.api(url, function (response) {
 alert(response.name);
 alert(response.email);
});
```

But the email field isn't there either unless I am putting that Graph api call in the wrong spot.  I removed it for now.

Below is my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

          //FACEBOOK login logic
            function statusChangeCallback(response) {
              if (response && response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken) {
                    debugger
                 Cookies.set("facebookToken",response.authResponse.accessToken, { expires: 7 })
              }

              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                facebookLogin();
              } else {
                // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.

              }
            }


            checkLoginState = function() {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
              });
            };

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                appId      : '---------', //update to environment appID 
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                                    // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
              });
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
              });

            };

            // async load of SDK 
            (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


          // backend call to send facebook login token to API
            let facebookToken = Cookies.getJSON("facebookToken");

            function facebookLogin() {
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: 'https://REMOVED/login',
                  //header: 'origin',
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   data: JSON.stringify({
                        "facebookToken": facebookToken
                   }),
                   success: function(data, status, xhr)
                   {
                      if(Cookies.getJSON('facebookToken')) {
                        Cookies.set("login",data.newToken, { expires: 7 });
                        $.ajax({
                           type: "GET",
                           url: 'https://REMOVED/status',
                           headers: { 'Authorization': data.newToken },
                           success: function(data)
                           {    
                             Cookies.set("subscription",data, { expires: 7 })
                             window.location.href = "/pages/account";
                           }                    
                        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                          console.log("FAILED ON STATUS");
                        });
                      }
                   }
               }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                    $("#result").text("There was an issue with your facebook login. Please try again.");
               });
          };
```

Comment: The email address will be only returned if the email address is valid and public

Comment: it's valid and public -- it's a test account

Comment: So your Facebook app is not live is that correct ? Then are you logging in as Test user or Facebook account added in the App as admin, developer or tester ?